# ls does not show a hidden file (OS X)

Tags: files, ls, open-files, lsof

I am using `lsof` to view the list of open files.
One such file that it displays open is :

```
Google    3864 malaykeshav   46u     REG                1,1 470455334 32578671 /Users/malaykeshav/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/.com.google.Chrome.CiGbDZ
```

But when I go to the location and run a `sudo ls -al` no such file is displayed.
How do I access this file?

My current directory where I am executing `ls` is

```
$pwd
/Users/malaykeshav/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash
```

`lsof` displays this file open after exectuing `ls`.

Comment: the file maybe not exist anymore, if you open a file, it can be loaded into ram and then delete and being open as long as your program run it. try to restart `chrome`

Comment: Even after loading it onto RAM and deleteing it from the drive, the `lsof` will display it ?

Comment: Yes, it's in fact one technic used by hackers to lunch a proxy sock on a corrupted server and delete all config and executable file. if the server is never rebooted, and nobody noticed the sock process, it runs without being physically on the disk.

Comment: @Kiwi, it's not about _loaded into ram_. If it's open by a process, a file is not removed _from disk_ when it's unlinked from the last directory it was linked to. Kyuubi, yes on MacOS/X, at least with the lsof provided by Apple, lsof reports it even if the file has been unlinked. On Linux, you see `(deleted)` appended to the end of the filename.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the precision. I tend to simplify a bit too much and not understand every process ;)

Comment: @Kyuubi what if you restart `chrome`, does the file still open ?

Comment: @Kiwy : Restarting Chrome removed the file as expected. I was actually trying to save a video stream that had been buffered in chrome.